# Java 6 with NTLM2

Tags: java, ntlm, ntlmv2

I have a component that is written in C# to overcome NTLM2 authentication protocol (or at least that what I was told)

I'd like to convert this component to Java 6 - will java support the NTLM2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java 6 classes support  NTLM v2. Check [Http Authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html) in Java for an example of how to enable it.